# Cursor get stuck in frame 1 Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cursor

Every time I revisit frame 1, a duplicated cursor will pop up. When going onto frame 2 then hitting a back button to frame 1, a cursor will get stuck but also a new cursor will come up which means I have two cursor in one frame.

Any help please?

Thank You

```
stage.addChild(pencil);

pencil.mouseEnabled = false;
pencil.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor(event:Event)

    pencil.x = stage.mouseX;
    pencil.y = stage.mouseY;

Mouse.hide();
```

Comment: Are you creating a custom cursor, or is it just the default operating system cursor that's showing up more than once?

Comment: Provide your code or an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: this only goes on frame 1? I've only inputted into frame 1

Comment: IT'S OK! I GOT IT TO WORK AGAIN! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Writing code in frames - bad practice.

But you can avoid re-executing the code in many ways. For example

```
var executed:Boolean;
if (executed) return;
executed = true;
// ----------------
stage.addChild(pencil);

pencil.mouseEnabled = false;
pencil.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor(event:Event)

    pencil.x = stage.mouseX;
    pencil.y = stage.mouseY;

Mouse.hide();
```